# What is the difference between the login.salesforce.com and login.database.com hosts?

Tags: integration

I am automating the import process from Salesforce.com into a database. I am given the option to select login.salesforce.com and login.database.com as the host. What is the difference between the login.salesforce.com and login.database.com hosts?

Comment: Database.com is a pure database whereas force.com is an application development framework. If you do not want a UI after you upload the data, then Database.com might be an option.

Comment: Thanks, Shalini. Do they both use the same database? If I run a "select * from accounts" query on both Salesforce.com and Database.com will they return the same list of accounts?

Comment: I have not tried it, but I guess so. Check this link https://bighadoop.wordpress.com/2013/10/14/database-com-salesforce-coms-cloud-database/